# Normal Netstat?

Tags: 14.04, networking, streaming, netstat

So I used netstat to see any listening ports, and the following is the result. Does anyone know if this is a normal result? What is the keyring-Ru86sa/control one? Thanks!

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13321    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12922    @/tmp/dbus-c7kJWiTC


unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19485    @jacob-
```

com.canonical.Unity.Master.Scope.applications.T13381377631412

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11968    /tmp/.ICE-unix/1714

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14355    /run/user/1000/keyring-Ru86sa/control

unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     10374    /run/udev/control

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12283    /var/run/cups/cups.sock

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13674    /run/user/1000/keyring-Ru86sa/pkcs11

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13678    /run/user/1000/keyring-Ru86sa/gpg

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13679    /run/user/1000/keyring-Ru86sa/ssh

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11967    @/tmp/.ICE-

unix/1714

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14538    /run/user/1000/pulse/native

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13320    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10583    /var/run/sdp

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16145    @jacob-com.canonical.Unity.Scope.applications.T13386294834370

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7675     @/com/ubuntu/upstart

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14445    @/tmp/dbus-UGCnuAEyHF

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18199    @jacob-com.canonical.Unity.Scope.files.T13382231338828

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13627    @/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1556

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13645    @/tmp/dbus-N7VAFsxG2a

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9601     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10626    /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16144    @jacob-
```

com.canonical.Unity.Scope.scopes.T13386286307737

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10764    /var/run/acpid.socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19486    @jacob-com.canonical.Unity.Master.Scope.files.T13381385701249
```

i

Answer (score 2):

Check the first column, it says `unix`, that means these are Unix domain sockets. The Unix domain socket is a form of IPC (Inter Process Communication) mechanism among various processes within a given system.

So, in a nutshell, this is perfectly normal.